# Tezos Frozen in Failed Transaction

Tags: error, tzstats

I really need some help on this.

I had 26,720.726 Tezos available in my account which was stored in a Trezor Model T and I used simplestaking.com to access my Tezos. I wanted to send my entire balance to Atomic Wallet and the interface said the transaction cost was 0.01 so I subtracted that from the amount I was sending (so I sent 26,720.716). The transaction never arrived in my Atomic Wallet. My wallet shows the full balance in my account still and it simultaneously shows a debit from my account for -26,720.726174 Tezos.

When I look at the transaction on tzstats it says the transaction "failed" and "backtracked" BUT it is showing a debit from my account. You can see the transaction here on the tracking tool: https://tzstats.com/opLfpc4jnwQ8goFkXk1eJnDxogpPhyNiNBswmLTHcst2oKHFjcU.

I tried to send a test amount of 100 to atomic wallet afterwards and it gives me an error message that says:

```
TrezorConnect: tezosSignTransaction
error: Device call in progress
```

This is what the error message looks like when I try to re-send even a small amount (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1weo4whihamyjj8/Screenshot%202020-05-04%2000.03.06.png?dl=0)

Can you tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem bith using binance. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, never risk more than you can afford. Secondly, your funds are not stuck. If you look at your address, https://tzstats.com/tz1WBKfsPLp94D7wscTRn8KFt9pBfEopdUYr, everything is still there. As the operation shows, the operation backtracked so, no, nothing transfered.

Restart your trezor and try the transfer again. Remember, your tokens are stored on the chain, not in the device.

Comment: thanks for your reply, utdrmac. I restarted my computer (twice) and retried a very small transfer of 100 tezos multiple times and I get the same error. I tried on another computer as well and got the same error message. I had accessed my tokens via wallet.simplestaking.com and someone at simplestaking.com said to directly access my tezos via their interface instead of using the trezor interface. I tried that but got the same error message. If you have any other ideas I would love to hear, please and thank you :-)

Comment: You're getting that same Trezor error message each time? That's an issue with your Trezor device. I suggest contact Trezor for support or looking through their forums. It's not a "tezos" issue. You might need to format your Trezor and restore the wallet using your mnemonic words.

Comment: thanks again. I have a video call today with simplestaking.com/ who handles the wallet for trezor and they issued a bug fix yesterday but it didn't fully resolve the problem. They are working on it and should have a fix soon. Looks like the software bridge that connects to the trezor is buggy right now because there was a recent software update on the trezor. seems like all will be resolved soon(ish)

Comment: @GrantRomundt Great. Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem except a small amount. I transferred a small amount of XTZ from my coinbase account to simplestaking via my Trezor T.  That went fine.  Then a couple of days later, I tried to send the XTZ back to coinbase.  The same thing happened that you described.  I opened a chat with simplestaking to ask what the problem is.  According to them, it is a known issue that is related to the latest Trezor connect update.  They said they are working on a fix.  They didn't tell me what will happen when they fix the bug.  So I don't know if the transaction will eventually go through or it will just be canceled and the fee returned.  My guess it will just be canceled and I will have to transfer later.  The reason I was doing this small transfer of XTZ to/from coinbase was to test simplestaking to decide if I wanted to move all my XTZ there....LOL

However, whenever I plan on transferring a large amount of anything, I always first transfer a small amount to ensure it transfers as expected.  This bug reinforces in me why I do this.  I would rather pay a small extra fee then have an unnerving situation occur with a large amount.

Update:  I went back on simplestaking a week later and the transaction was voided and the XTZ back in the wallet.  However, I see they still charged the transfer 0.010 fee.  I don't think they should be charging the fee with something like that.  Does anyone know if this bug has been fixed yet?  I don't want to try again until I hear it's fixed.